# LDAP Connection Pooling with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, connection-pooling, spring-ldap

I was trying setup LDAP connection pooling using spring security and xml based configuration.

Below is my configuration,

```
 <authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
      <ldap-authentication-provider server-ref="ldapServer"
       user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=users"
       group-search-filter="(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember={0}))"
       group-search-base="ou=groups"
       group-role-attribute="cn"
       role-prefix="ROLE_"
       user-context-mapper-ref="ldapContextMapperImpl">
      </ldap-authentication-provider> 
 </authentication-manager>
```

How do i provide all the connection pooling configuration?
I am intending to use PoolingContextSource class as it provides properties to configure pool size etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pooled connections doesn't work with authentication, because the way LDAP authentication works is that the connection is authenticated on creation.

Comment: If this is the case, then why is manager DN and password given? As per my understanding, client connects to the LDAP server using manger dn and password and later send bind request which has the user dn and password which is used for authentication. So the initial connection which was created using manger dn and password - is it not pooled?

Comment: Also as per above, in a web application, if LDAP based authentication via BIND operation is being used then every user that logs in creates its own ldap connection. This would lead to many ldap connections. Is there not any way to create a pool and reuse connections for these? How do we set the idle or timeout for these connections atleast?

Comment: The connection created for each individual user should be automatically closed by the Spring LDAP infrastructure, so you shouldn't have to worry about that. In addition to this, a manager LDAP connection will be created and used for searching for the user before authentication. This connection will also be automatically closed and this should - in theory - be possible to pool, but it appears the ldap-server XML doesn't support this. The ldap-server element only appears to create a ContextSource instance though, so you might try creating an <ldap:context-source> and using that instead.

Comment: As you said manager connection will be used to search user before authentication. Once the user is authenticated, are the roles for the user retrieved using manager connection? What if the authenticated user doesnt have permissions to query his roles? Is there a way to use manager connection to query roles of an authenticated user? currently using <ldap-authentication-provider> tag, i didnt see any such option.

Answer (score 2):

They explicitly removed pooling for ldap binds (or in Spring's case an `authenticate`):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/issues/216

`ldapTemplate.authenticate` searches for the user and calls `contextSource.getContext` to perform the ldap bind.

```
private AuthenticationStatus authenticate(Name base,
                            String filter,
                            String password,
                            SearchControls searchControls,
                            final AuthenticatedLdapEntryContextCallback callback,
                            final AuthenticationErrorCallback errorCallback) {

    List<LdapEntryIdentification> result = search(base, filter, searchControls, new LdapEntryIdentificationContextMapper());
    if (result.size() == 0) {
        String msg = "No results found for search, base: '" + base + "'; filter: '" + filter + "'.";
        LOG.info(msg);
        return AuthenticationStatus.EMPTYRESULT;
    } else if (result.size() > 1) {
        String msg = "base: '" + base + "'; filter: '" + filter + "'.";
        throw new IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException(msg, 1, result.size());
    }

    final LdapEntryIdentification entryIdentification = result.get(0);

    try {
        DirContext ctx = contextSource.getContext(entryIdentification.getAbsoluteName().toString(), password);
        executeWithContext(new ContextExecutor<Object>() {
            public Object executeWithContext(DirContext ctx) throws javax.naming.NamingException {
                callback.executeWithContext(ctx, entryIdentification);
                return null;
            }
        }, ctx);
        return AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.debug("Authentication failed for entry with DN '" + entryIdentification.getAbsoluteName() + "'", e);
        errorCallback.execute(e);
        return AuthenticationStatus.UNDEFINED_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

By default, context sources disable pooling. From `AbstractContextSource.java` (which is what `LdapContextSource` inherits from):

```
public abstract class AbstractContextSource implements BaseLdapPathContextSource, InitializingBean {
...
    public DirContext getContext(String principal, String credentials) {
        // This method is typically called for authentication purposes, which means that we
        // should explicitly disable pooling in case passwords are changed (LDAP-183).
        return doGetContext(principal, credentials, EXPLICITLY_DISABLE_POOLING);
    }

    private DirContext doGetContext(String principal, String credentials, boolean explicitlyDisablePooling) {
      Hashtable<String, Object> env = getAuthenticatedEnv(principal, credentials);
      if(explicitlyDisablePooling) {
          env.remove(SUN_LDAP_POOLING_FLAG);
      }

      DirContext ctx = createContext(env);

      try {
          authenticationStrategy.processContextAfterCreation(ctx, principal, credentials);
          return ctx;
      }
      catch (NamingException e) {
          closeContext(ctx);
          throw LdapUtils.convertLdapException(e);
      }
  }
...
}
```

And if you try to use the `PoolingContextSource`, then you will get an `UnsupportedOperationException` when `authenticate` tries to call `getContext`:

```
public class PoolingContextSource
        extends DelegatingBaseLdapPathContextSourceSupport
        implements ContextSource, DisposableBean {

...
    @Override
    public DirContext getContext(String principal, String credentials) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported for this implementation");
    }
}
```

This code is from the `spring-ldap-core 2.3.1.RELEASE` maven artifact.

You can still do connection pooling for ldap searches using the `PoolingContextSource`, but connection pooling for authenticates won't work.